# Multi-line regex with specific beginning and end?

Tags: regular-expression

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

I'm trying to get started with `include-search`, and since I'm working in golang right now, I'm trying to get vim to include a set of imported files.

E.g.

```
1    import (
2        "foo"
3        _path "bar"
4        "baz"
5    )
```

I want everything inside double-quotes, between lines 1 and 5.
I got as far as the following but it still only matches one line:

`/\v^import \((\n\s+"\zs.*\ze")*`

Comment: This is a limitation of vim’s regex :( it’s hard (not impossible) to get multiline matches. I wonder if it’s easier to just match import lines, and use includeexpr to find all the bits between parens?

Comment: It may theoretically be possible with zero-width but 2nd paragraph of [`:h /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/\@%3C=) tells us it's not if you have multiple lines you want to "ignore". I got `\(^import (\([^"]*"[^"]\+"\)\{-}\)\@<=[^"]*"\zs[^"]\+\ze"` match each files of your example if they are joined in one line. But even there, setting `include` to this pattern only finds the first one. @dbenknoble I don't know if `includeexpr` can import multiple files as it is also used for `gf`. Nevertheless, @harv maybe look how/if [`vim-go`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) does it.